# Android - how to change the dependency list?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

I have been using android-support-v4 in my app. And, this week, I have added a tabbed activity which (using eclipse) added android-support-v13 to my project.

I now get this warning when I export my project:

> WARNING: Found both android-support-v4 and android-support-v13 in the
>   dependency list.

My problem is that I cannot find any trace of android-support-v4 in my project (except for within android-support-v13).

Can someone help me out with the steps I need to follow in order to remove android-support-v4 from my project.

Comment: this is why you should move to android studio.

Comment: I will after this - for my own sanity...